# customize the look of thunderbird chat conversations

Tags: css, chat, thunderbird

How do I customize the look of Thunderbird chat (conversations area). I am able to customize the side bar that is shown for for mail tab using css code that I put into userChrome.css and that customization works. So it seems all I need to know is a bit of css that I can use to do the same thing for the conversations area in the chat tab. For reference the css code I am using in userChrome.css that does work is as follows:

```
    treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {background-color: #aaa !important;}
    treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected, focus) {background-color: Highlight !important;}
```

Comment: this question was related to a version of thunderbird available 2013 and is probably obsolete at this point.